# Error notification on mule flows

Tags: error-handling, notifications, mule

I am relatively new to mule and Im wondering if there is a built in error notification if there an error on a mule flow or if this can be set up in the mmc to trigger an alert if something is wrong with the flow. Please advise.

Thanks and Have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in several ways.

1. The MMC can do [log analysis](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.7/working-with-alerts) send an email if matches a certain pattern.
2. You can simply had an exception handling in the flow like a Catch Exception and do the send of a mail there, [I wrote a blog post](http://www.toforge.com/2016/01/create-mule-common-libraries/) having has sample this case
3. You can use [mule notification](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-server-notifications) system to create a java class that will manage this notification, maybe using log4j SMTP appender to easily send notification mails.

This are my opinion about the 3 methods

1. First method relies on the mmc being up, mmc creates load on your mule server anyway by making calls and in some production environnement it may be disabled depending on the internal policy of the company. Furthermore if for some reasons goes down you will not receive any notification so you also need to make sure your mmc stays high available. Not an option for me.
2. I find this method the most appropriate as is it similar to standard exception handling in programming. Manage your exception when you need to and never let them pass silently. When needed send some via mail.
3. This approach is not bad but not my favorite because lot of times you will see "fake exception" coming in that you need to filter. One example is when a client stops the connection to mule (closing the browser for example) you will get a socket exception that mule cannot write back, this is totally normal and I don't think you want to be spammed by this kind of mail. If you really want to use this system than keep in mind you will need to filter non critical exceptions.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi Mauro,Thank you so much as this is indeed very helpful. Is it possible to get all the exception messages? as of now I can only get the last exception ' 1.  Invalid argument 2.  Unable to create a canonical file 3. **error on the email**

Comment: Can you be more specific. what you mean by get all possible exceptions and which of the 3 cases ?

Comment: Hi Mauro,When I check the logs I can see 3 exceptions. one says invalid argument, second says it cannot create a file and third is the technical log which im getting from '#[exception.getMessage()] '. Is it possible to get the other errors as well?

Comment: I think I got it using the '#[exception.getCause()]'

Comment: Sometime to be really sure I use ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e) of apache commons. Just pay attention in some limit cases, like exception raised from filters, there is only on level of exceptions and getRootCouse return null.

Comment: hi Mauro, your'e right. I find that very useful but not for this case. Thanks again for all the help and guidance. really appreciate it, Cheers